# I deleted files in AppData/Packages and some apps does'n work

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, appdata

I'm stupid and I deleted files in Windows 8.1 on my Surface Pro files in AppData/Packages folder. Now some apps doesn't work, especially all in metro (Windows Store too). How can I fix this? I dont have any backup, even I dont have Windows 8 installation disc cause i bought it with my Surface Pro..

Comment: Probably best to go into the settings app and click "refresh your PC". If that doesn't work, try "remove everything". Note that the latter option will delete all your files.

Answer (score 2):

Make new User account in Windows set it as  administrator and delete old account.

This will leads to create your new AppData folder so now you can work with your control panel and windows App.

Answer (score 0):

Run a CMD window with Admin rights and type:

powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:systemRoot\WinStore\AppxManifest.XML

That will fix Windows Store.